# Different Panels for page with & without argument

Tags: uri, views

the scenario:
I do have the following path-auto configuration for Articles path:

```
domain.com/category/subcategory/article-title.
```

I woud like to use different panel for:

```
domain.com/category
```

and different for

```
domain.com/category/subcategory
```

So I have created basic page with alias `domain.com/category` and panel, where selection rules are:

- URL path= 'category'
- url path is not 'category/*/*' to allow displaying articles with their own paths
- php code which checks if page has no arguments

On the panel I've  set the view with no contextual filter.

The second panel gots the same rules (except php checking if page has arguments) and is displaying second view with contextual filter and pane rule for fetching argument set to get argument from panel (first one).

the above combination is not working. I know I can set alias path directly in view but really want to use panels with views included for better power in page-elements.

Can anyone please tell me how to get it working - different panels for page with first argument, different without and no panel for page with 2 arguments.

Thanks for any help!
The second panel

Comment: Setup the path as /!category/!subcategory then assign both arguments as term id contexts. Then create two panel variants with the selection rules context exists !category and the other variant !subcategory exists.

Comment: thanks! if I assign argument as term id context I can access the page but when i add selection following rule to variant: 'when context exists' and select to that argument term id context - the page can't be found (argument provided to URL). Why ?